# Interpolation from one color to another and back

Tags: c++, algorithm

In my program, I am trying to go from a start Color-> end Color -> start color and so on.

The question is not specific to any language though I am writing this snippet from my own framework code.

Note: `lerp modifies the color` while `getLerped returns new value`

```
startProgram(){
ofColor startColor; //set as 152,219,255
ofColor endColor; //set as 132,152,184
ofColor lerpedColor = startColor;
float colorShift = 0.01f; 
}
```

**//inside the function in my program that is fired continuously per frame**

```
if(lerpedColor == endColor){
            endColor.set(startColor);
            startColor.set(lerpedColor);
            lerpedColor.set(startColor);
            cout<<"Swapping end color"<<"\n";
            cout<<"Start Color: "<<ofToString(startColor)<<"\n";
            cout<<"End Color: "<<ofToString(endColor)<<"\n";
            cout<<"Lerped Color: "<<ofToString(lerpedColor)<<"\n";
     }

    lerpedColor.lerp(endColor,colorShift);
    cout<<"Lerped color"<<ofToString(lerpedColor)<<"\n";
```

My color interpolation from the initial start Color to the end color is happening fine but this doesn't go back from the end Color to the star Color back.

The `if condition` for `lerpedColor == endColor` is fired only once when I get the following couts:
startColor: 132,152,184
endColor: 152,219,255
lerpedColor: 132,152,184

What's going wrong in here that the interpolation from happens only once and not back?

Comment: Whak kind of "lerpedColors" do you get instead? Given that there's no startvalue passed to your lerp function, I'd think that your linear interpolation is not uniform.

Comment: After the first time, the `if condition` is fired, the lerpedColor is always (132,152,184) and startColor is always (132,152,184). Refer to the end of my post

Comment: Hard to say what's wrong without seeing the body of the lerp() function...

Comment: What happens when you switch the start and end colour manually (that is, have the program go originalEnd -> originalStart -> originalEnd). Does it work? Perhaps in this direction, lerp is a NOP (rounding errors etc.)?

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: Check here the screenshot - http://i.imgur.com/0istw.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct *uniform* linear interpolation could be implemented as:

```
int interp(int src, int dst, float time) {
    return src*(1.0-time)+dst*time;
 }  // where 0.0<=time<=1.0
```

When there are 3 colors to be interpolated at once, one possibility is to take the max color difference:

```
Color diff = abs(end - start); // diff.x = abs(end.x - start.x) etc.
int steps = max(diff);
int a=0;
lerp(src, end, (float)a/(float)steps);
a++;
if (a==steps) {  // swap start/end 
}
```

In this case there largest color difference will be decremented/incremented by one and the other components will be actually interpolated.

Comment: Whoa! That's correct. I checked back to manually interchanging the endColor and startColor and `Lerp` in that framework doesn't give changed colors. Shoot!

Comment: I was trying to avoid so much manual work of changin each colors value through your kind of interpolation. Is there no other way I could go by using something readymade as `lerp` function somewhere?

Comment: In C++ you should be able to use a vector library that has the operators +,- and scalar * defined. Also you most likely want to implement integer number of steps as in my second revision.